# Is list(dict.items()) thread-safe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is the usage of `list(d.items())` in the example below safe?

```py
import threading

n = 2000

d = {}

def dict_to_list():
    while True:
        list(d.items())  # is this safe to do?

def modify():
    for i in range(n):
        d[i] = i

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=dict_to_list, daemon=True)
    t1.start()

    t2 = threading.Thread(target=modify, daemon=True)
    t2.start()
    t2.join()
```

The background behind this question is that an iterator over a dictionary item view checks on every step whether the dictionary size changed, as the following example illustrates.

```py
d = {}
view = d.items()  # this is an iterable
it = iter(view)  # this is an iterator
d[1] = 1
print(list(view))  # this is ok, it prints [(1, 1)]
print(list(it))  # this raises a RuntimeError because the size of the dictionary changed
```

So if the call to `list(...)` in the first example above can be interrupted (i.e., the thread `t1` could release the GIL), the first example might cause RuntimeErrors to occur in thread `t1`. There are sources that claim the operation is not atomic, see [here](https://blog.labix.org/2008/06/27/watch-out-for-listdictkeys-in-python-3). However, I haven't been able to get the first example to crash.

I understand that the safe thing to do here would be to use some locks instead of trying to rely on the atomicity of certain operations. However, I'm debugging an issue in a third party library that uses similar code and that I cannot necessarily change directly.

Comment: I am pretty convinced from reading your linked article that it is not safe in python 3.x

Comment: Are you looking for a way to trigger this so you can know beyond a doubt that it is indeed an issue?  I'm guessing you are facing a steep wall in that scenario and want to be double sure before embarking in the direction of refactoring a huge code base?

Comment: I see the same thing you're seeing.  Ex 1: I was not able to get `list(d.items()` to crash.  Ex 2: I replaced it with `it = iter(d.items())    try:        while True:            next(it)        except StopIteration:            pass` -- which is your 2nd example -- I got `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`.  So, working on the iterator directly triggers exception (immediately), yet if you pass `d.items()` directly to `list`, both threads seems fine.

Comment: Correct, I essentially would like a way to trigger a RuntimeError for the first example or an explanation of why it is safe. My understanding is that it should not be safe, but I haven't had any success it getting it to raise this RuntimeError yet.

Comment: I've started reading through the CPython implementation of list and dict, but I'm not familiar enough with the inner workings of the Python interpreter and the GIL to understand whether the RuntimeError could actually occur here.

Comment: "Each bytecode instruction and therefore all the C implementation code reached from each instruction is therefore atomic from the point of view of a Python program" and `dict.items()` seems to be atomic at least https://docs.python.org/3/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe

Comment: @Boris none of the atomic examples there showcase `values()`, `items()` or `keys()`.  I do agree that they could be atomic in theory because it only returns an iterator.  I wonder why they would not list them yet list `extend()`, `update()`, `pop()`, `append()`

Comment: @RazzleShazl it explicitly shows that `D.keys()` is atomic and `.items()` is also [implemented in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b4f9089d4aa787c5b74134c98e5f0f11d9e63095/Objects/dictobject.c#L2321) just like [`keys()` is](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b4f9089d4aa787c5b74134c98e5f0f11d9e63095/Objects/dictobject.c#L2235), so I assume it is atomic too.

Comment: It will be more interesting if the program randomly sleep between operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: it might be fine but use a lock anyway.

Using [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) you can see that `list(d.items())` is effectively two bytecode instructions (`6` and `8`):

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("list(d.items())")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (list)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (d)
              4 LOAD_METHOD              2 (items)
              6 CALL_METHOD              0
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

On the Python FAQ it says that (generally) things implemented in C are atomic (from the point of view of a running Python program):

> [What kinds of global value mutation are thread-safe?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe)
>
> In general, Python offers to switch among threads only between bytecode instructions; [...]. Each bytecode instruction and therefore all the C implementation code reached from each instruction is therefore atomic from the point of view of a Python program.
>
> [...]
>
> For example, the following operations are all atomic [...]
>
> ```py
> D.keys()
> ```

[`list()` is implemented in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b4f9089d4aa787c5b74134c98e5f0f11d9e63095/Objects/listobject.c#L140) and [`d.items()` is implemented in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b4f9089d4aa787c5b74134c98e5f0f11d9e63095/Objects/dictobject.c#L2872) so each should be atomic, unless they end up somehow calling out to Python code (which can happen if they call out to a dunder method that you overrode using a Python implementation) or if you're using a subclass of `dict` and not a real `dict` or if their C implementation [releases the GIL](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#releasing-the-gil-from-extension-code). It's [not a good idea](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#218-threading) to rely on them being atomic.

You mention that `iter()` will error if its underlying iterable changes size, but that's not relevant here because `.keys()`, `.values()` and `.items()` return a [view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) and those have no problem with the underlying object changing:

```py
d = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
view = d.items()
print(list(view))  # [("a", 1), ("b", 2)]
d["c"] = 3         # this could happen in a different thread
print(list(view))  # [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)]
```

If you're modifying the dict in more than one instruction at a time, you'll sometimes get `d` in an inconsistent state where some of the modifications have been made and some haven't yet, but you shouldn't get a `RuntimeError` like you do with `iter()`, unless you modify it in a way that's non-atomic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What you say about `list(dict.items())` being 2 operations matches with my shallow understanding of how Python works internally. Both directly map to respective functions in C. If a C function can indeed never be interrupted (and that's the piece that I'm uncertain about) that would mean that the first example in my question cannot throw a RuntimeError. But then why does the source I'm referencing warn about `list(dict.items())` potentially throwing exceptions? It would be great to get another answer from somebody who understands the internals at play here.  :-)

Comment: By the way, I'm not concerned about the last case you mentioned. The dictionary might of course be in an arbitrary state when `list(dict.items())` is called. I'm ok with that as long as I don't get a RuntimeError.

Comment: @user14278279 I edited in some ways those functions might stop being atomic (and also the way you're modifying the dict probably has to be atomic too) and removed that second part, since yea, it's not relevant to what you were asking.

Comment: ah! the bits I don't like about python. The implementation-specific nightmare.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the author of that article was confused about dict views, thinking `dict.items` returns an iter**ator** like `dict.iteritems` did in Python 2, not an iter**able** like it does in Python 3. Note that that article was written almost 13 years ago, five months before [Python 3.0 was released](https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.0/). Btw, as [PEP 3106](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/) says (emphasis mine):

> The **original** plan was to simply let .keys(), .values() and .items() return an iter**ator**, i.e. exactly what iterkeys(), itervalues() and iteritems() return in Python 2.x.

Python 2, `iteritems` gives an iter**ator**:

```
>>> d = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
>>> items = d.iteritems()
>>> items
<dictionary-itemiterator object at 0x0000000003EBA958>
>>> next(items)
(1, 1)
>>> list(items)
[(2, 2), (3, 3)]
>>> list(items)
[]
```

Python 3, `items` gives an iter**able**, not an iter**ator**:

```
>>> d = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
>>> items = d.items()
>>> items
dict_items([(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)])
>>> next(items)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    next(items)
TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not an iterator
>>> list(items)
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
>>> list(items)
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
```

And in Python 2, with the iter**ator**, this does cause the error:

```
>>> d = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
>>> items = d.iteritems()
>>> d[4] = 4
>>> next(items)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    next(items)
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

In Python 3, if `d.items()` *did* return an iterator, i.e., if it were equivalent to `iter(d.items())`, then it would be unsafe. Because your thread might get interrupted between the iterator creation by `iter()` and the consumption by `list()`. But since it returns an iter**able**, it's the `list()` function itself that *internally* creates an iter**ator** from the iterable, so both the iterator creation and its consumption happen during *the same* single bytecode instruction (executing the `list()` function).

If you change your code to `list(iter(d.items()))` and increase `n` to let's say `20000000`, then you'll likely get the error. Example from a run on [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/BSgMxEIbveYqhXhKQRdeLCMGX6E0kBJPsjjSTJZlSivjs67Sp1YP4HzL5ycyX@Zcjz4UeHpe6rpiXUhl4rtEHpEkpAgvjXZdSQdzHp9SYIOAbOy5uh421eVIgOsy4i7Ct@9j9Sed35Fh1GKTkpo0xADeATT6So/kUgQuE8tzJuQRMx29mKhUQkKB6mqIm84MOL/gqG6FSmMA58jk6B9bCxrnskZzb9Ga@l7ZrqmF7vmn2dYpsfwe5heBjLmRPGcxldmjSKRlV9@M/rL76X5TxSrnY94Kkzbp@AQ):

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File ".code.tio", line 9, in dict_to_list
    list(iter(d.items()))  # is this safe to do?
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```